# How to enable echo service in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking

I want to test my UDP client send/receive cycle with [echo service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol), but there is no `/etc/inetd.conf` mentioned in Wikipedia page in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu normally ships without inetd (or xinetd), you can install it and configure it to run an echo server.

Standalone echo servers are also available.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

From 2006 Ubuntu started to use upstart instead of sysvinit.

But then in 2010 after a battle [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) prevailed over upstart.

So to enable the service you need, it is best to work with systemd nowdays. You can check the systemd conf file `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.